# Python socket programming: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets

I am sending ssh count data from 'alphaclient' to 'alphaserver'. However the alphaclient server is not able to connect with alphaserver. Kindly help me resolve this error. I tried to kill the process at the port and restart the VMs but still getting the same issue.

This is the error output in alphaclient:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//./sshlogin-counter/alphaclient.py", line 82, in <module>
    inform_alphaserver(client_message)
  File "//./sshlogin-counter/alphaclient.py", line 45, in inform_alphaserver
    c.connect((alphaserver_ip,port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

and this is the output in alphaserver:

```
Binding alphaserver at port 7888
Server Socket created.
Server socket binded at port 7888
Listening to port...
```

alphaclient.py

```
import os
import socket



input_file = os.path.join('/','var', 'log', 'auth.log') 
#output_file = os.path.join('.','sshlogin-counter','client_message.txt')
total_ssh_attempts = 0  



#Function1 that reads /var/log/auth.log and returns total ssh attempts made into that VM
def ssh_attempts(input_file):
        
    successful_ssh_attempts = 0
    invalid_ssh_attempts = 0
    current_ssh_attempts = 0
    
    with open(input_file,'r') as f:
        f = f.readlines() #list of lines
        for line in f:
            if 'sshd' and 'Accepted publickey' in line:
                successful_ssh_attempts+=1
            #elif 'sshd' and 'Invalid user' in line:
                #invalid_ssh_attempts+=1
        current_ssh_attempts = successful_ssh_attempts + invalid_ssh_attempts
        
    return (current_ssh_attempts)
  
    
    
#Function2 that informs Alphaserver of new ssh login attempts
def inform_alphaserver(client_message):
    port = 7888
    alphaserver_hostname = socket.gethostname() 
    alphaserver_ip = socket.gethostbyname(alphaserver_hostname)
    
  
    print('Establishing connection with {} at port {} ...'.format(alphaserver_ip,port))

    
    c = socket.socket()
    print('Client socket created...')
           
    c.connect((alphaserver_ip,port))   
    print('Client socket connected with {} at port {}'.format(alphaserver_ip, port))
       
    client_message = client_message.encode()
    print("Sending client message...")
    
    c.send(client_message)
    print("Message has been transmitted to alphaserver successfully")        
          
    c.close()
    print("Connection Closed!!!")
        
    
    
#Monitor new ssh login attempts
while True:
   
    #Function 1
    current_ssh_attempts  = ssh_attempts(input_file)
    
    #Condition to test if new login attempts made
    if current_ssh_attempts > total_ssh_attempts:
        total_ssh_attempts = current_ssh_attempts
        print('SSH login attempts detected!!!')
        
       
        client_message = '{} had {} attempt'.format(socket.gethostname(), total_ssh_attempts)
        
        #Function 2
        #Send output file to Alphaserver
        inform_alphaserver(client_message)
```

alphaserver.py

```
import os
import socket 



#File for storing messages from Alphaclient 
client_messages = os.path.join ('.','sshlogin-counter','client_messages.txt')



#Function that listens to client servers and receives client data
def receive_clientmessage():
  port = 7888
  host = socket.gethostname()

  print('Binding {} at port {}'.format(host,port))

  s = socket.socket()
  print('Server Socket created.')


  s.bind((host, port))
  print('Server socket binded at port {}'.format(port))

  s.listen(2)
  print('Listening to port...') 
  
  while True: 
    c , addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected with {}".format(addr))

    client_message = c.recv(1024).decode()
    client_hostname = list(str(client_message).split(" "))[0] #str converted to list and list[0] is the client_hostname 
    print("Client host name is {} ".format(client_hostname))

    c.close()
    break
    
  #s.close() 
  return (client_hostname, client_message)
  

    
   

#Function to write client data to client_message.
def update_client_messages(client_hostname, client_message):
  file = open(client_messages, 'r+')
  f = file.read()
  if client_hostname in f:
    position = f.index(client_hostname)
    file.seek(position)
    file.write(str(client_message))
    print('Updated client SSH login data')
    file.close()
  else:
    file = open(client_messages,'a')
    file.write('\n'+ str(client_message))
    print('Added new client SSH login data')
    file.close()

    

#Continuosly monitor and display client data    
while True:
  client_hostname, client_message = receive_clientmessage()
  update_client_messages(client_hostname, client_message)
  
  file = open(client_messages)
  content = file.read()
  print('----------------------------------------------------')
  print(content)
  print('----------------------------------------------------')
  file.close()
```

Comment: Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

Comment: Why do you say VMs? Are you using VMs?

Comment: Yes. I have deployed the python code in GCE instances

Comment: `s.bind((host, port))`: don't do that. Bind to `0.0.0.0`.